# LibGDX: Scene 2D Table, Is it possible to overlap two actors like an image and a label?

Tags: libgdx

The image below explains what I want to do.

The top diagram represents how I have the arrangement now.

The bottom diagram represents how I **want** the arrangement. Here is a diagram:

[image]

I wish for a label actor to be on top of an image actor.

Can this be done?

Comment: Use a `Stack` for the table cell?

Comment: @no one, looking at my answer below. My label has a 50% transparent black background (as a 9patch) covers up the whole image that it overlaps. Do you know how I can set the label to pack? or in other words not be the size of the image? I tried on the label calling pack() as well as setting width and height which did not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @noone for guiding me to the stack.  Please note my code is apart of a scroll pane. Also note the last item to be added to the stack will be on top. So that's why I add image and then the label.

```
Image image = new Image(texture);
Label buildingName = new Label(entry.getValue.name, skin, "building");
buildingName.setAlignment(Align.top);     
Stack stack = new Stack();  
stack.add(image);
stack.add(buildingName);
stack.addListener(buildItemUIListener); //used for click listener
stack.setName(entry.getKey()); //Used for the click listener 
table.add(stack);
```